# Select row by using one distinct column

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I have one table named `dictionarydefinition`.

```
CREATE TABLE dictionarydefinition (
id bigint NOT NULL,
definition character varying(1024) NOT NULL,
word character varying(200) NOT NULL,
grammertypename character varying(20) NOT NULL,
)
```

I have sql command `Select * from dictionarydefinition where word like 'someword%'`.

Results are multiple rows that got same value. For example if `someword%` is just empty ''
the result will be:

1. A
2. A
3. A
4. B
5. B
6. C
7. D
8. D
9. D

I just want result be:

1. A
2. B
3. C
4. D

I have used `GROUP BY` command, but it takes too much time to process 30MB database for my android device.

What kind of SQL commands I can add to make it choose only one row which got `someword%` value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the example you have mentioned, you can use GROUP BY.. Suppose the column-name for the alphabets is word, the command would be :

SELECT * from dictionarydefinition where word like 'someword%' GROUP BY word;

Comment: This method works, but it takes too much time to process 30MB database for my Android device. Is there some kind of optimal variant ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use SELECT TOP or LIMIT or ROWNUM

SELECT TOP 1 * from dictionarydefinition where word like 'someword%';

or

SELECT * from dictionarydefinition where word like 'someword%' LIMIT 1;

or

SELECT * from dictionarydefinition where word like 'someword%' AND ROWNUM <= 3